# How can i link *.ui widget to the derived class?

Tags: python, plot, widget, pyqtgraph

I am using pyqthraph in order to make a data monitoring program.

First, I opened qt desiner and added a few pyqtgraph.PlotWidgets.
Then I saved it as a ui file and called the file like:

```
uic.loadUi('untitle.ui', self)
```

It worked fine.

Then I created a `pyqtgraph.PlotWidget` derived class. But I don't know how to link the classes to ui.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using class promotion in Designer, as described in [1]. When you promote the PlotWidget in Designer, just specify the name of your custom class and module, rather than `pyqtgraph.PlotWidget`.

[1] http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/how_to_use.html#embedding-widgets-inside-pyqt-applications